# Google contacts via API

Tags: php, google-contacts-api

I want to fetch  Google contacts for users and create logs of new and updated contacts via a PHP script. Can someone please guide me on how to proceed?

I have implemented the same kind of service for calendar events using 0Auth2.0, but for contacts I didn't find any API in the Google PHP client libraries.

Comment: does this help:: http://code.google.com/p/google-api-php-client/source/browse/trunk/examples/contacts/simple.php

Comment: thanks for the link , i am able fetch  all contacts  using https://www.google.com/m8/feeds/contacts/default/full   , but how do i get full details of contacts like emailid ,address , mobile number .In the Contact id as  "http://www.google.com/m8/feeds/contacts/anrc.wipro%40gmail.com/base/121212a0w3e32"

Answer (score 0):

The problem is in the example, it seems that the json encoder does the mess.
One of the developers wrote how to achive email address on this link
http://pastebin.com/kAYT5Jng
You can see part of the discusion right [here](https://groups.google.com/forum/embed/?place=forum/google-contacts-api&showsearch=true#!topic/google-contacts-api/U63UnuqfMoA)

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried this project 
https://github.com/rapidwebltd/php-google-contacts-v3-api

Fetching all the contacts :

```
$contacts = rapidweb\googlecontacts\factories\ContactFactory::getAll();
var_dump($contacts);
```

create new contact

```
$name = "Frodo Baggins";
$phoneNumber = "06439111222";
$emailAddress = "frodo@example.com";
$note = "Note for example";

$newContact = rapidweb\googlecontacts\factories\ContactFactory::create($name, $phoneNumber, $emailAddress, $note);
```